# docker logs returns "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in"

Tags: php, docker, mysqli

I am a newbie to docker, and I am trying to follow the following [tutorial](https://dev.to/truthseekers/setup-a-basic-local-php-development-environment-in-docker-kod).

PHP service does not start after I add MySQL to docker. Dockefile has mysqli. I run it on locally on WSL. I looked online and I could find a solution.

I am getting the following output from docker-logs:

```
>/mnt/c/dev/docker-php$ docker logs 2bc9871bed18
Hello from the docker yooooo container
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in /var/www/html/index.php:5
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/index.php on line 5
Hello from the docker yooooo container
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'mysqli' not found in /var/www/html/index.php:5
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/index.php on line 5
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM php:7.4-apache
# COPY ./src /var/www/html
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
    # Use root/example user/password credentials
version: '3.1'

services:
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www/html/
    ports:
      - 80:80 
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html/
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: example

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

echo "Hello from the docker yooooo container";

$mysqli = new mysqli("db", "root", "example", "company1");

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, fav_color) VALUES('Lil Sneazy', 'Yellow')";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, fav_color) VALUES('Nick Jonas', 'Brown')";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, fav_color) VALUES('Maroon 5', 'Maroon')";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (name, fav_color) VALUES('Tommy Baker', '043A2B')";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);


$sql = 'SELECT * FROM users';

if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    while ($data = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $users[] = $data;
    }
}

foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo "<br>";
    echo $user->name . " " . $user->fav_color;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Try adding a `a2enmod mysqli` as well to your `Dockerfile`

Comment: I added "RUN a2enmod rewrite", but still getting that error in logs. Do I need to rebuild the image?

Comment: Could it be that extension is getting the wrong permissions?

# ls -la /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/mysqli.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 181184 Mar 10 22:14 /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718/mysqli.so

Answer (score 0):

As always for newbies, my troubles had a simple solution. I had to rebuild the container and it worked just fine:

```
docker-compose up --build
```